# mysql takes too long to restart (Large Database)

Tags: mysql, windows-server

I have a large db ( >20gb ). and since the maintenance downtime by our service provider this morning, I had tried to start the mysql but its been 7 hours. then I kill the service using task manager and restart the mysql again. but until now its still not up. its been 5 hours. Please advise.

MYSQL Version: 5.6
RAM : 14GB

These are the related mysql.log

```
2021-10-26 00:05:21 6256 [Note] mysql: Normal shutdown

2021-10-26 00:05:21 6256 [Note] Giving 1 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2021-10-26 00:05:21 6256 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2021-10-26 00:05:21 6256 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2021-10-26 00:05:23 6256 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2021-10-26 00:05:23 6256 [Note] Binlog end
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2021-10-26 00:05:24 6256 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2021-10-26 00:05:24 1bd4 InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to .\\ib_buffer_pool
2021-10-26 00:05:24 1bd4 InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 211026  0:05:24
2021-10-26 10:26:08 4104 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2021-10-26 10:26:08 4104 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2021-10-26 10:26:08 4104 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2021-10-26 10:26:08 4104 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-10-26 10:26:08 4104 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2021-10-26 10:26:08 4104 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2021-10-26 10:26:08 4104 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2021-10-26 10:26:09 4104 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 4.0G
2021-10-26 10:26:09 4104 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-10-26 10:26:11 4104 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2021-10-26 17:34:55 2600 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2021-10-26 17:34:55 2600 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2021-10-26 17:34:55 2600 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2021-10-26 17:34:55 2600 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-10-26 17:34:55 2600 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2021-10-26 17:34:55 2600 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2021-10-26 17:34:55 2600 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2021-10-26 17:34:55 2600 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 4.0G
2021-10-26 17:34:56 2600 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-10-26 17:34:57 2600 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
```

[image: on Task Manager, the mysqld.exe is listed with no status]

Comment: How much RAM?  What version of MySQL?

Comment: I have updated @RickJames

Comment: Does Task Manager show that mysqld is running?  Any other clues?

Comment: on task manager services, the mysqld status is "Starting", does this mean I just have to wait a bit more? its already 13 hours. @RickJames

Comment: Could you post HTOP or TOP output to verify available RAM on the server?  Any reason we can not see 'shutdown complete' after the buffer pool was dumped?